# How do I remove the development console from my desktop app?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

After building and deploying my app, the development console is appearing in the bottom left corner. How do I disable it?

Comment: Do you mean in Unity?

Comment: Not in unity. It is appearing in the app itselft.

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you're asking for here, can you add a screenshot of what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: DevBuild]

Uncheck the Development Build and then build your application, it will no longer be visible.

Update: Solution 2
Create a script and put the below code into it.

```
void Update()
{
  Debug.developerConsoleVisible = false;
}
```

Comment: This didn't help.

Comment: @holodoubts then please post a screenshot of what you meant.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOhlE.png  I want this to disappear from the app

Comment: @holodoubts try solution 2.